# Using multiple pricebooks in an opportunity

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

When adding products to an opportunity I can only use one pricebook.
In my case I need products from multiple pricebooks.
How can that be done?

Comment: could you please share your ideas of using multiple pricebooks in an opportunity. currently i am trying to design this one...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this out of the box. One of our goals in my company's project is to build this in Visualforce/Apex Code. It's actually pretty trivial code, but it requires some rather curious workarounds. You'll basically want a custom object for price books, another for price book entries. From there, you can use lookups on the opportunity/opportunity line item to use the custom objects. Behind the scenes, you'd have triggers create new price books and price book entries that the standard system is expecting. As such, you'll need a custom "add line items" page and "edit line items" page.

Comment: wow, I expected this to be supported. Now I need to figure out how I workaround this without development. Any idea?

Comment: If by 'without development', you mean no VF or Apex, then I don't believe it can be accomplished without those.

Comment: @sfdcfox, could you please share your ideas with some more detail.

Comment: But the Opportunity Line Item has a PricebookEntryid field lookup to Pricebook Entry object and which is required. How can add a custom Price book-entry object id to this field, please explain.

Comment: @sfdcfox if you were to do this today. Can this be done in LWC?

Comment: @jsmith It's been a super-long time since I've worked there, but I recall we had a Visualforce page that collected the data, and then in the controller, we would create a new Price Book, assign the Price Book to the Opportunity, then create the Price Book Entries, and finally create the Opportunity Line Items. No custom object or fields were involved, just a custom UI.

Comment: @compski Yes, I love working with LWC, and I'd gladly give almost anything an attempt in it if I had the chance.